# How to divide large image (10 000 x 10 000 and bigger) from data stream on WP7 / Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am working on some project for Windows Phone 7, where I have loaded large image (resolution 10 000x10 000 and bigger) in data stream and I need divide this 
large image into smaller pieces from that stream.

Is there any C# library which I could use? Or can you prompt me how to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That's a challenge! The typical mobile phone hasn't enough main memory to load the full uncompressed image into memory. There are libraries that can manipulate JPEG images by only partially decompressing them. What format is the image? And wouldn't it be possible to send the image in pieces in the first place (like Google Maps)?

Comment: It´s a JPEG. I am loading that image from phone media library, I save it into data stream and I need manipulate with that stream. Split it into smaller JPEGs.

Answer (score 5):

Is that not the purpose of the silverlight DeepZoom technology? Maybe that would fit your purpose.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/03/28/deep-zoom-on-wp7.aspx

Comment: that is exactly the way to go. really great work with sea dragon.

Comment: I am not sure if Deep Zoom can solve my problem. I need to work with data stream where i have loaded that image and I need to split that stream into smaller JPEGs. Probably by hand because I can´t find library which can do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you geting this image from?
I'd guess from a web service/server somewhere.

I'd move the image processing to a webserver/service too.

A large image would likely take a lot of processing on the device. You could do this faster on the server and therefore make your app more responsive. You could also start showing smaller images sooner on the device as it wouldn't have to download the larger one. If multiple clients wanted the same larger image then you could cache the data on the web servers and so subsequent requests for images (by other users/devices) would be served even faster.

On the server (assuming you can run .net there too) you could then use the [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class to edit the image as needed.

Comment: I am loading this image from phone media library. I have loaded this image into data stream and I need to divide this stream into smaller jpeg images. Any ideas?